# Dragon NaturallySpeaking: Speak the punctuation while training?

Tags: voice, dragon-naturally-speaking

When performing the general training in Dragon NaturallySpeaking, the user must read from passages of text such as from "2001: A Space Odyssey". When reading these passages, should the user pronounce punctuation? Should the user state "period", "comma", and "quote"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking the punctuation while training is optional as you can see in the screenshot below taken during training. I personally never do it and I have no issue when dictating punctuations afterward (French and English with Dragon 10, 11, 11.5, 12 and 12.5).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Speaking the punctuation is the norm. IIRC, there is a mode that will insert commas and periods automatically, but it's not enabled by default in the new v12.0.

Answer (score 0):

That is what is normally done in training and in normal use.

Comment: What is normally done in training and in normal use? Speaking the punctuation, or not speaking the punctuation?